# SQL query interchange code with value like 1= active query attached

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to show code name while in the database it is saved as code number.

How to display code name?

```
like code is 1 , 2
```

In the database the code is stored and I want to show `1= active, 2 = expire`

How to show active expire as result?

My current query is:

```
select code from post code
```

Comment: I think you just want the `case` expression, but the question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you have number as code and want to show a name, this can be done like following.

```
SELECT *,
(
 CASE code WHEN 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Expire' END
) AS CodeName
 FROM [post code]
```

Comment: I'd recommend changing this to WHEN 2 THEN 'Expire' ELSE 'Other' to ensure unexpected values are discoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Depending in what do you want. 
To select all fields and add the last one you want to show:

```
SELECT *, IIF(code = 2, 'Expire', 'Active') Code_Status From [post code]
```

If not:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, IIF(code = 2, 'Expire', 'Active') Code_Status From [post code]
```

Also if you can have more codes and  not just 1 and 2:

```
SELECT *, IIF(code = 2, 'Expire', IIF(code = 1, 'Active', code)) Code_Status From [post code]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query :

```
select CASE code 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Active' WHEN 2 THEN 'Expire' END as code 
from [post code]
where code in(1, 2)
```